# ¿Cómo puedo aplicar nitidez a una imagen con CSS?

Tags: html, css

¿Qué contenido tengo que insertar en el CSS para que la imagen tenga tanta nitidez como yo quiera? Me sirve también si se usa la etiqueta canvas con una imagen, no tiene porque ser esa imagen en concreto, puede ser una forma cualquiera. Gracias de antemano

```css
.aplicarnitidez {

}
```

```html
<img width="300px" height="175px" src="https://d500.epimg.net/cincodias/imagenes/2018/11/13/lifestyle/1542113135_776401_1542116070_noticia_normal.jpg" class="aplicarnitidez">
```

Comment: Define *nitidez*, lo más parecido a alterar *brillo, saturación y contraste* lo logras con la función `hsla()` en un atributo [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color). Saludos

Comment: Otra opción es usar la propiedad [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/filter), pero debes tomar en cuenta la compatibilidad, ya que no todos los navegadores soportan esta característica. Igual todo va a depender de lo que entiendas por *nitidez* y lo que pretendes hacer con la imagen.

Comment: Compartiendo todo lo comentado por Mauricio, hasta la fecha no es posible hacer lo que buscas sin acudir a "hacks" de diseño. Una opción puede ser mix-blend, mira este ejemplo: https://codepen.io/giana/pen/pPLodQ?editors=1100

Comment: También te recomiendo para estos casos el formato svg dan una mayor calidad